# Magento 1.9 contact form reply to address

Tags: magento-1.9

Since upgrading to 1.9.3 and changing to the RWD theme my contact form now have a reply to of our address instead of the customers email addresses so that when I click reply, the email comes back to me instead of going back to the customer?

Does anyone know why this would have started happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: has anyone else experienced this issue as i still has not been resovled